# mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1323x9248 and 1568x32)

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, speech-recognition, transformer-model

I am using a Conformer package from Github:
[Conformer](https://github.com/sooftware/conformer)

Raw data is converted to a Dataloader containing spectograms for audio and the translation converted to numbers using a Dictionary.

These are the shapes of my input, input_len, target, target_len where batch size=27

```
torch.Size([27])
torch.Size([27, 20])
torch.Size([27])
```

This is the setup I am running (only using first batch to check that is working before training with all the batches)

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from conformer import Conformer

cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()  
device = torch.device('cuda' if cuda else 'cpu')

################################################################################

# batch_size, dim, sequence_length= 27, 201, 1162

for idx, (audio, audio_len, translations, translation_len) in enumerate(loader):
    inputs=audio.to(device)
    input_lengths=audio_len
    targets=translations.to(device)
    target_lengths=translation_len
    break

model = nn.DataParallel(Conformer(num_classes=6030, input_dim=201, 
                                  encoder_dim=32, num_encoder_layers=3, 
                                  decoder_dim=32)).to(device)

outputs = model(inputs, input_lengths, targets, target_lengths)
```

This is the error I am getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-50bacd198d81> in <module>()
     43 
     44 # Forward propagate
---> 45 outputs = model(inputs, input_lengths, targets, target_lengths)

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1846     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight, bias):
   1847         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight, bias), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1848     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1849 
   1850 

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1323x9248 and 1568x32)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post the full error trace here as *text*, *not* image; see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Can you add the model code? There is mismatch in output dimension of a linear layer and input of the next linear layer.

Comment: @JodhSingh
the model code can be found in the package, here [link](https://github.com/sooftware/conformer/tree/main/conformer)